# Compute exact zoom in scrollView

Tags: ios, swift

This is the current view that I made:

[image]

- The black part is the scrollView.
- Inside the scrollView is the ImageView.
- The image is landscape.

What I want to achieve is to make the top and bottom of image to fit the scrollView by setting the minimumZoomScale.

Comment: You can set imageView's contentMode  `imageView.contentMode = .aspectFill` and you should set contentView into scrollView after that you can put your imageView into contentView with top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints.

Comment: @EmreCiftci, I tried to set the contentMode to aspectFill but the scrollView won't scroll anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are having layout much like aspect fit mode then you can have black part either on top/bottom or left/right. You will need to check which aspect ratio is larger. Check the following:

```
func getZoomScaleToFillSize(_ contentSize: CGSize, inFrame viewFrame: CGRect) -> CGFloat {
    let contentAspect = contentSize.width/contentSize.height
    let panelAspect = viewFrame.width/viewFrame.height
    if(contentAspect > panelAspect) {
        // Means it will be black on top and on bottom
        return contentAspect/panelAspect
    } else {
        // Means it will be black on left and right
        return panelAspect/contentAspect
    }
}
```

So in both cases we need to zoom in a bit. In your case `contentSize` should the size of your image. And `viewFrame` should be the frame of your scroll view. The result should be amount of zoom that needs to be applied to make it "fill" and black part should just disappear.

Comment: I tested this and sort of works on 6 plus but not on XR. In XR there is still a small black part remaining.

Comment: @jay123456 Seems strange. Perhaps you are computing this too early and views are later being laid out and resized.

Comment: I moved it to viewDidLayoutSubviews and it now works in XR but in 6plus it's too zoom (but it's fine). Just want to know why.

Comment: @jay123456 Hard to say why. Layouts are extremely problematic when you need to compute something like this. I know it's not the best solution but for this case it might be better if you could compute the scroll view frame from screen size instead of using it's frame when doing the layout. This way you would avoid all the problems but you will have the logic in 2 places (constraints in storyboard and formula in code) so you will need to remember that if one changes so must the other.