# Compute minimum zoom scale of uiscrollview

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

Hi I have an image with a size of 1205x1162 and a scrollview of 414x442. So the image is way bigger than the scrollview. What I want is to zoom out the image to fit the width (if the image is portrait) or height (if the image is landscape) to the scrollview.

Comment: What you have tried so far ??

Comment: I have tried the opposite of this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56886377/compute-exact-zoom-in-scrollview/56886965?noredirect=1#comment100342903_56886965 but won't work.

Answer (score 0):

SV -> ScrollView
I  -> Image

For portrait:
SV.frame.width / I.size.width

For landscape:
SV.frame.height / I.size.height